# OkHttp request HTTPS is very slow on Android

Tags: android, https, okhttp

HTTPS request cast about One min...
My request url is https://auth.timeface.cn/aliyun/sts.
The server is use TLS 1.0 and AES_256_CBC encode.
I got those message from Chrome tip.

So my code is like

```
    String serverAddress = "https://auth.timeface.cn/aliyun/sts";
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    if (serverAddress.contains("https")) {
        ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_0)
                .cipherSuites(CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
                .supportsTlsExtensions(true)
                .build();

        httpClient.setConnectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
        httpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        httpClient.setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(serverAddress)
            .get()
            .build();

    Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    String responseStr = response.body().string();
```

Why?

Something wrong about my usage?

Answer (score -1):

The execute method blocks your main thread, which means it stops your app until the network call is done. You should use enqueue method to make [asynchronous call](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes).

```
  String serverAddress = "https://auth.timeface.cn/aliyun/sts";
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    if (serverAddress.contains("https")) {
        ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_0)
                .cipherSuites(CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
                .supportsTlsExtensions(true)
                .build();

        httpClient.setConnectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
        httpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        httpClient.setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }

 Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(serverAddress)
        .build();

    httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
      @Override public void onFailure(Request request, Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
      }

      @Override public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

        String responseStr = response.body().string();
      }
    });
```

just provide ProgressBar before the call and remove them on onFailure() and onResponse()